# Using stepclass in klaR package

Tags: r

I'm working on a 1500 rows data with 22 variables.

I would like to use stepclass to do variable selection.
However, I have a hard time on the Criterion option.

```
stepclass(x, grouping, method, improvement = 0.05, maxvar = Inf,
start.vars = NULL, direction = c("both", "forward", "backward"),
criterion = "CR", fold = 10, cv.groups = NULL, output = TRUE,
min1var = TRUE, ...)
```

```
criterion:
CR Correctness Rate
AC Accuracy
AS Ability to Separate
CF Confidence
```

```
Details
• The correctness rate is the estimator for the correctness of a classification rule (1-error rate).
• The accuracy is based on the euclidean distances between (scaled) membership vectors and the
vectors representing the true class corner. These distances are standardized so that a measure
of 1 is achieved if all vectors lie in the correct corners and 0 if they all lie in the center.
• Analougously, the ability to seperate is based on the distances between (scaled) membership
vectors and the vector representing the corresponding assigned class corner.
• The confidence is the mean of the membership values of the assigned classes.
```

After I check the details in documents, I can't tell what's difference between **Accuracy(AC)** and **Ability to Separate (AS)**.

What's the exactly meaning of these two?

Thank you in advance!